# Http request from kafka queue in NiFi

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

is it possible to receive a message from kafka by sending an http request?[image]

Ideally I would like to receive messages depending on the request

Comment: Are you familiar with the Kafka REST Proxy?

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to receive a message from kafka by sending an http request?

Nope. `ConsumeKafka` does not take input from other processors, so it will never poll Kafka as a direct result of another processor communicating with it.